# propeller flying physics for the layman

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, gyroscopes, popular-science

I'm starting a (quad?)copter build, and i can find plenty of knowledge about stabilizing the craft and things related to gyroscopy.

but there's absolutely zero information on things that help me decide for

- central propellers and central body mass?
- central propellers and peripheral body mass?
- quad propellers?
- if quad, what's the optimum distance?
- should I put the propellers in tubes?

and the considerations:

- which design has better control?
- which design has better power efficiency?

and several others questions that quadcopter forums simply ignore...

i could ask each combination of them here and bore you all to death, but instead the question is: How do I start to learn about that subject?

keywords and easy to absorb works would be perfect! thank you.

PS: just a few samples of the variations in design done with no regard for science! 
[image]

[image]

[image]

edit: could get some information on the designs changes when going from a one propeller to 4 in the quadcopter wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrotor